# How To Reply To A Message Sent By The Bot Itself

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

I want the bot to reply to its help message by saying "this message is now inactive".

here's the code:

```
mm = await message.send(embed=embed1)
    await mm.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    await mm.add_reaction("2️⃣")
    await mm.add_reaction("3️⃣")
    try:
        while True:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check,timeout=10)
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                await mm.edit(embed=embed1)
            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
                await mm.edit(embed=embedZ)
            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "3️⃣":
                await mm.edit(embed=embed3)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await mm.reply('...')
```

error: `'message' object has no attribute called 'reply'`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None)


@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    sent_msg = await ctx.send("An great help command")
    await sent_msg.reply("this message is now inactive")


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Which would result in :
[image: Bot in action]
Bot replies to its own help command

--- Answer to new edit ---

I have made a function to do this. It is stripped from my older project so you may remove the unnecessary features you don't need :

```py
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import typing
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")

async def paginate(
    ctx: discord.ext.commands.context.Context,
    *embed_pages: typing.Union[discord.Embed, list[discord.Embed]],
    content=None,
    overwrite_footer=True,
    timeout=None,
):

    if isinstance(embed_pages[0], list):
        embed_pages = embed_pages[0]

    every_embed = list()
    if overwrite_footer:
        for index, each_embed in enumerate(embed_pages):
            each_embed.remove_footer()
            each_embed.set_footer(text=f"Page {index + 1} of {len(embed_pages)}")
            every_embed.append(each_embed)
    else:
        every_embed = embed_pages[:]

    sent_embed = await ctx.send(
        content=content, embed=every_embed[0]
    )  # Send the first page
    page_index = 0  # Set the starting index

    reactions = ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣"]
    for each_reaction in reactions:
        await sent_embed.add_reaction(each_reaction)

    while True:
        try:
            payload = await bot.wait_for(
                "raw_reaction_add",
                check=lambda payload: payload.message_id == sent_embed.id
                and not payload.member == bot.user
                and payload.member.id
                == ctx.author.id,  # Do this if you want it to be author-only
                timeout=timeout,
            )
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            # timeout has been hit
            await sent_embed.reply("This message is now inactive")
            try:
                await sent_embed.clear_reactions()
            except discord.Forbidden:
                # No perms
                pass
            return
        else:
            try:
                await sent_embed.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, payload.member)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                # Bot does not have permission
                pass

            if (
                str(payload.emoji.name) not in reactions
            ):  # Some user reacted with something else
                pass

            elif str(payload.emoji.name) == reactions[0]:  # One
                page_index = 0
                await sent_embed.edit(embed=every_embed[page_index], content=content)

            elif str(payload.emoji.name) == reactions[1]: # Two
                page_index = 1
                await sent_embed.edit(embed=every_embed[page_index], content=content)

            else:
                page_index = 2
                await sent_embed.edit(embed=every_embed[page_index], content=content)

@bot.command(aliases=["start",])
async def start_pages(ctx):
    
    await paginate(ctx, discord.Embed(title="Abc", description="sdknfe"),
    discord.Embed(title="idk", description="something else"),
    discord.Embed(title='(¬_¬")', description="We really need 3 pages"),
    timeout=10)

    
bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

This code will result in [this](https://youtu.be/XBW1ms3Lrz4)

Comment: its not working achxy

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If yes please provide them. @BotBoi345

Comment: 'message' object has no attribute called 'reply'

Comment: [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message) does have an attribute [`reply`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message.reply). If you have made any changes to the aforementioned code could you provide that too? Also which fork of `discord.py` are you using? (like `pycord`, `nextcord`, `disnake`, etc)

Comment: im new so i dont know which fork im using

Comment: Oh, that's completely fine. Could you provide the code you used?

Comment: ok let me add the code

Comment: Check the edited answer , @BotBoi345